What can I do when a garage won't fix reoccuring fault codes?
I bought my Nissan Juke Hybrid on 1/3/23. Since May, I have had the car back and forth to the garage four times due to reoccurring engine lights and a HEV malfunction in which the car lost all power and the RAC had to be phoned. RAC immediately found fault codes indicating a problem with the inverter and took the car to the garage to be fixed. The next day,the garage informed me that there was nothing they could do as according to them there wasn't a fault with the vehicle. Since then,the car has faulted again and everytime the Nissan engineer's reset the codes and insist that there isn't a fault. I have spoken to Nissan customer services,who don't seem to have any idea what to do,my case manager acknowledges that the car is faulty but stated that his hands are tied and there is nothing he can do. I've repeatedly asked to speak to a manager at head office but they refuse to ring me. The main codes that keep reoccurring are P1A2C-01 (inverter locks PEB 1) and U2113-87 (CAN Comm err VSP) alongside other codes suggesting a fault with the HV battery and HV battery 2. I'm a new mum who is at her wits end, nobody at Nissan is taking me seriously and I'm so worried and anxious about the safety of this vehicle, especially with my baby inside. Can anyone give me any guidance?
Diagnostic Codes
System Type: ENGINE SYSTEM TEST/ALUES
Name: HR16-DIAGNOSE
DTC: C284,unknown

System Type: ELECTRO DRIVE
Name: ELECTRIC VEHICLE ELECTRONIC CONTROL UNIT - DIAGNOSE
DTC: DTC1623,PEB access trap interlock state on inverter

System Type: ELECTRO DRIVE
Name: HSG (HYBRID STARTER GENERATOR) INVERTER - DIAGNOSE
DTC: DTC1A2C,PEB Interlock

System Type: ENGINE SYSTEM TESTVALUES
Name: H4D - DIAGNOSE; H5H- DIAGNOSE
DTC: DTCC284,LIN bus OFF

METER/M8A  248106PA3C  U2113-87 CAN comm err (VSP) CRNT GENRTR 291700356R
P1A2C-01 Inverter locks PEB 1.DEF
PAST

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
